# How to preserve scroll state when calling router.refresh() in Next JS app router

Tags: reactjs, scrollbar, next.js13, next-router, app-router

I'm in a Next JS 13 app router page with the following layout:

[image: App layout]

When clicking on a star icon, I'm updating some state in the DB and the containing card (green client cmp) is moved to the top of the list as a consequence. To update the list (brown server cmp), I'm calling `router.refresh()` after performing the DB update.

Unfortunately, this call to `router.refresh()` resets the scroll position of the list and I'm "moved" back to the top of the list which is rather unpleasant as a user.

Is there a way for me to actively prevent this change to the scroll position?

Comment: any solution???

Comment: Haven't found anything so far but am also still interested.

I do have an idea by adding a "client cmp" wrapper around the list but I'm not sure if this would work. Also it's rather clumsy to implement and I don't have much time to try this ATM.

However, I'll post an update if I ever find the time to try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that this has nothing to do with server components & router refresh at all. This also happens in a vanilla react client component without anything Next specific and the reason is that I'm updating the order of `key`s in my rendered list when moving the newly starred item to the top.

Can be fixed by simply applying CSS [overflow-anchor: none](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-anchor) to each list item.

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/27044), where you can find more details about why this is happening in the first place.